# Error creating SQL Network Name on Azure SQL Cluster in Azure AD

Tags: sql, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, failovercluster, azure-availability-set

I am trying to create a SQL Failover clustered instance in Azure with two nodes joined via Azure Active Directory.  I have been following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-portal-sql-create-failover-cluster) guide.

Along with several other web resources when I've hit a wall, and I've hit quite a few walls in getting the Windows Cluster set up.  Now that this is done I've tried to install SQL on the top of it per step 4 of the referenced installation guide.

The SQL install completes successfully right up until the installation progress bar is at 100% and then generates an error:
[image: The Cluster resource SQL Server could not be bougt online due to an error bringing the dependency resource SQL Network Name online]

Now in a normal active directory fixing that would be a simple matter of giving the cluster name object the permissions to "create object" in the OU, but I really don't have any idea how to do that when we are using **Azure Active Directory**.

I have tried elevating the permissions of the account doing the installation and even the service account the SQL Instance is running under, as those appear to be the only permissions levers I can pull in AAD.

Is an Azure VM SQL FCI even possible in AAD?  How do I give the cluster the permission it needs to create the SQL Name?

*If I need to blow everything away and start again this is inconvenient - but possible - this is a test configuration.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonably certain it won't work with Azure AD. But you can use existing templates to spin up sql cluster from scratch:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/sqlvm-alwayson-cluster
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/301-sql-alwayson-md-ilb-zones